# css style and inline style not working in outlook 2007

Tags: html, css

I have a html newsletter page. I need to send it to the given mail id. In Outlook , I'm unable to see the my styled html page but in browser css and inline style works perfectly. So why in Outlook does not work inline or Css style?

Comment: Mail clients, in general, are terrible at supporting CSS (generally, only inline styles - not even inline stylesheets - will work). Live with that.

Comment: "why" - not constructive. "How to fix that" - you need to provide more detail before we can answer.

Comment: How you coded your HTML i mean Div's or table... in Outlook Div's will not work you have to code with the help of tables only...

Comment: I used Div's in my html page. So with help of tables we can do this?

Answer (score 2):

To get good cross-compatibility it's wise to go with last centuries web practices.

Use tables for structure, style inline, use pixel measurements and be prepared for images to fail.

These basics provide robust results in most clients.

Answer (score 0):

Its best to also avoid background images since these wont work either in outlook.